# No output from program to find all palindrome numbers within a given range

Tags: java

Create a java program to find and print all palindrome numbers within `b` and `a`
such that `a<3000`, `b<3000`and `b<a`.
My approach:-

```
import java.util.*;
class PalinDrome_Within_A_Range_Of_Two_Numbers{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an upper limit<3000");
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a lower limit <3000,upper limit");
        int b=sc.nextInt();

        int c=0;
        int d,e,f,j;
        for(int i=b;i<=a;i++){
            j=(int)(Math.log10(i) + 1);
            e=0;
            f=0;
            d=i;
            for(int k=1;k<=j;k++){
                f=i%10;
                f=(int)(f*(Math.pow(10,(j-k))));
                i=(i-(i%10))/10;
                e=e+f; 
            }
            if(e==d){
                c=c+1;
                System.out.println("The "+c+"th Palindrome number between "+b+" and "+a+" is "+d);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this program, nothing appears in the output after giving the two integers.

Comment: Try a debugger. If this is too big of a step for you at the moment, try sticking in `System.out.println()` calls to tell you the values of varibles at critical places, and check if they are as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the first number, if it is not a palindrome, will end the loop at the `else break;` statement. To fix the problem, you should also not manipulate `i` within its loop, but rather a copy of it.

You may think about debugging. Shows you the point of failure faster than Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sour you enter uper limit before entering the lower limit because I by intuition added lower limit first and it did not work any way here is a simpler soultion if you want

```
public class PalinDrome_Within_A_Range_Of_Two_Numbers {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an upper limit<3000");
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a lower limit <3000,upper limit");
    int b=sc.nextInt();

    int c=0;
    int d,e,f,j;
    for(int i=b;i<=a;i++){
        String num = String.valueOf(i);
        String reversNum = getReversStr(num);
        if(num.equals(reversNum)){
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
}

private static String getReversStr(String num) {
    char[] chars = num.toCharArray();
    char[] revers = new char[chars.length];
    for(int i = chars.length;i>0;i--)
        revers[chars.length-i]=chars[i-1];
    return new String(revers);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Others already suggested to use a debugger. That makes sense because your code is quite complicated. (By the way, you should keep the scope of your variables as small as possible to make your code more readable. It makes no sense to declare and initialize a variable outside a loop when it is used only inside the loop body.)

A better approach would be to simplify your code. You could split it into multiple functions and give each of these a meaningful name.

Or you could use a completely different approach. Being a palindrome is not so much a property of the number itself but of its string representation. So why not base the whole algorithm on strings:

```
for (int i = b; i <= a; i++) {
    String num = String.valueOf(i);
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString();
    if (num.equals(reverse)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your code (no guarantee that they are the only two, but solving them should get you a step further at the least).

1. You are using `i` as control variable in your outer loop, and then you are modifying `i` inside your inner loop (`i=(i-(i%10))/10;`). Since you are taking a copy of `i` into `d` anyway, there is a simple fix: do the modification on `d` instead of on `i`.
2. The `break;` statement in you else part will break out of the outer loop if the first number tried (`b`) is not a palindrome. I think you can just delete the else part.

I tried entering 102 as upper limit and 99 as lower. Your program correctly prints `The 1th Palindrome number between 99 and 102 is 99`, but then because `i` has been modified goes into an infinite loop. So you are on the way.

I agree with what others have said about breaking your code up in less comlex methods. This will also allow unit testing each method, which will help to locate bugs. Better variable names will help understanding the code, not least when you ask others to take a look. Finally, don’t declare a variable until you need it, this will also help readability.